# Give users acces to admin a single post or set up WP network?

Tags: multisite, user-roles, user-access

I have a directory styled site in which companies are listed. I would like to give the owners of the companies(the ones on my site) the option to take control of the content in their company entry. Some entries would still be controlled by myself.

The question arises should I give owners admin access to their respective entry through user roles and some custom plugin code, or set up a WP multi-user site/network. Not sure how the WP network works in great detail but figured I would ask for opinions. I'd need to transfer the site over to the network version somehow, or set a function to go to the Network site if one exists for that company/entry. Not sure how that would work.

Things I need the owners to be able to do:
Update Categories, images, pot thumb nails and content(includes some additional met boxes with text input) as well as several other meta boxes.

While I can still control content on the entries without an external admin.

Thanx for any and all help/opinions in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need wordpress multisite to implement this feature. Just use normal wordpress. I recommend you two plugins.

1) [Role scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/screenshots/)

2) [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/screenshots/)

Make sure you enabled user registration in **Admin -> Settings -> General**

All the best

Answer (score 0):

Multisite is going to be overkill for your scenario–the way I understand it, you only have a "site", not "sites". If you just want to give a group of users access to edit one page, I would recommend a Plugin that further limits user Roles, as @Viruthagiri suggests.